# UserEntity$Description and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, lombok

I am developing the **Spring Boot + MongoDB** example and I am getting below error.

I used Lombok to generate setters and getters. I am simply calling the repositoy.findAll() method and giving me the below error.

> ## Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Feb 10 16:49:04 IST 2018There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class com.myfi.model.UserEntity$Description and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.myfi.model.UserEntity$Description and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.myfi.model.Tweet["user"]->com.myfi.model.User["entities"]->com.myfi.model.UserEntity["description"])

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same issue in my project.

For me, my problem was I was running the application within eclipse, and eclipse was not aware of the lombok annotations. When I [added the lombok plugin to eclipse](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) it started working